# iPhone custom delegate problem

Tags: iphone, ios, delegation

I have set up a delegate for my class 'HotRequest', but am having problems implementing it. The code for my class is below. Any ideas? Thanks

**HotRequest.h**

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@protocol HotRequestDelegate;

@interface HotRequest : NSObject {
    NSString *requestString;
    id <HotRequestDelegate> delegate;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *requestString;
@property (nonatomic, assign) id <HotRequestDelegate> delegate;

- (id)initWithRequestOptions:(NSDictionary*)dict;

@end

@protocol HotRequestDelegate <NSObject>
@required
- (void)requestComplete;
@end
```

**HotRequest.m**

```
#import "HotRequest.h"

@implementation HotRequest

@synthesize requestString, delegate;

- (id)initWithRequestOptions:(NSDictionary*)dict {
    if ((self = [super init])) {
        for (NSString *key in [dict allKeys]) {
            requestString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@&%@=%@", requestString, key, [dict objectForKey:key]];
        }
        NSLog(@"%@", requestString);
    }
    [delegate requestComplete];
    return self;
}

@end
```

**WelcomeViewController.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "HotRequest.h"

@interface WelcomeViewController : UIViewController <HotRequestDelegate>{
     HotRequest *myRequest;
}

@property (nonatomic,retain) HotRequest *myRequest;

@end
```

**WelcomeViewController.m**

```
#import "WelcomeViewController.h"
#import "HotRequest.h"

@implementation WelcomeViewController
@synthesize myRequest;
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    NSDictionary *mydict = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:@"2", @"1", @"4", @"3", nil];
    myRequest = [[HotRequest alloc] initWithRequestOptions:mydict];
    [[self myRequest] setDelegate:self];
}

- (void)requestComplete {
    NSLog(@"request complete");
}
@end
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`delegate` is still `nil` in `initWithRequestOptions:`. You are trying to call the delegate method before setting the delegate.

Comment: Not nil, actually - undefined, which is worse, since it will cause a crash.

Comment: @Echelon: you are mistaken. On object allocation, all instance variables are zeroed out.

Comment: I knew it had to be something stupid that I was doing. Thanks a lot.

Comment: yes, of course, you're dead right - alloc ultimately calls calloc().